# Count Down in Service

Tags: android, service, countdown

I want to make Programm where a countdown is included. I want the countdown to keep on running even if the app is closed. I know i should use getter and setter.

Edit: Every time I press the button, I get an error. Does any one know how i can fix this?

starting the Service:

```
        public void onClick(View arg0) {                            //countdown starts by preesing a button
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ssf = Integer.parseInt(essf.getText().toString());
            Intent openCountDownService = new Intent("julian.mangelberger.ultravioletobservation.COUNTDOWNSERVICE");
            startService(openCountDownService);
        }
```

Service:

```
import julian.mangelberger.ultravioletobservation.TabMainActivity;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;

public class CountDownService extends IntentService {

public CountDownService(String name) {
    super(name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    while (TabMainActivity.progressBarStatus <= 100) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TabMainActivity.progressBarStatus++;
        TabMainActivity.progressbar1.setProgress(TabMainActivity.progressBarStatus);

    }
}


}
```

Comment: it does not work^^. Every time I press the Button I get an error. I will edit my question.

Comment: @user1838978 : what is the error you get?

Comment: The application has been closed. Try again.

Comment: beacause are you running a gui code in background and in android 4? please paste the exception stacktrace, android version

Comment: i am using android api8. Whats the exception stacktrace? sorry i am nuew to android and english is not my native language.